# Fatal error "R_TempDir" contains space

Tags: r

Descargué R 4.2.0 en Windows 10, pero no cuando quiero abrirlo me envía ese mensaje de error: ""Fatal error "R_TempDir" contains space""
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje te abre una buena oportunidad para aprender sobre variables de entorno
en R.

Lo que dice el mensaje es que el directorio de archivos temporales usado por R
tiene un espacio.

`TMPDIR`, `TMP` y `TEMP` son variables usadas por R para reconocer el diretorio de archivos temporales. Si no existen, R usa el valor de la variable `R_USER`

Los directorios de la variable no deben tener espacios ni caracteres especiales (Mira el manual en R-admin > Running R).

Entonces, para resolver tu problema debes incluir como valor de la variable "TMP" un directorio que no tenga espacios ni caracteres especiales.

Existen tres formas de realizar eso:

### Definir el valor desde un terminal.

Como en el ejemplo del manual:

```sh
   "path_to_R\bin\x64\Rgui.exe" TMP="aqui el directorio"
```

### Crear un archivo ".Rprofile" en el "home" de R o en otro directorio que sea leído por R.

Dentro de ese archivo escribes el valor de la variable:

TMP = "aqui el directorio"

Desde R puedes escribir el archivo al directorio que desees, con el siguiente código (usa "TMP" o "TMPDIR"):

```
 write("TMPDIR = '<aqui el directorio tmp>'",
        file=file.path(aqui el 'path' donde deseas escribir el Renviron', '.Renviron'))
```

### Usar la interface gráfica de Windows para cambiar el valor de la variable en el panel de control:

‘User Accounts’ > Account > ‘Change my environment variables’.

El manual detalla el proceso:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-set-environment-variables_003f

Para acceder a la ayuda de R puedes usar lo siguiente en la consola:

```
?tempdir
```

El siguiente comando debe mostrar el valor actual de la variable en tu sesión.

```
tmpdir()
```

Answer (score 0):

El error "R_Tempdir contains space" indica que el directorio temporal de R contiene un espacio en su ruta.

Para solucionar este problema, se puede cambiar el directorio temporal de R a uno que no contenga espacios en su ruta. En Windows hay que editar las variables de entorno y agregar en variables del sistema la variable TMPDIR con un valor que haga referencia a una carpeta sin espacios por ejemplo c:\temporal